# Hclust object from Factorminer does not cluster dendrogram in Pheatmap

Tags: r, hclust, pheatmap

Cross posted:  https://www.biostars.org/p/450365/

I am trying to create a heatmap of a matrix with 20 rows and 10 columns using `pheatmap::pheatmap`. To cluster the columns, I am using an `hclust` object obtained after running `FactoMineR::HCPC` on the input matrix. However, when I use the hclust object, the

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pheatmap)
library(FactoMineR)

# reproducible df of 20 rows and 10 columns
set.seed(100)
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 20, ncol = 10)
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
colnames(tmp) <- paste0('col_', seq(1:ncol(tmp)))
rownames(tmp) <- paste0('row_', seq(1:nrow(tmp)))

# use FactoMineR HCPC for clustering data
res.pcahcpc <- FactoMineR::PCA(X = t(tmp), graph = F)
res.pcahcpc <- FactoMineR::HCPC(res.pcahcpc, nb.clust = 4, graph = F)

# get hclust object from FactoMineR::HCPC
pcahcpc.tree <- res.pcahcpc$call$t$tree

# hclust object
> pcahcpc.tree

Call:
flashClust::hclust(d = dissi, method = method, members = weight)

Cluster method   : ward 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 10 

# get cluster information for heatmap annotation
res.pcahcpc <- res.pcahcpc$data.clust # clusters
colnames(res.pcahcpc)[ncol(res.pcahcpc)] <- "PCA_HCPC"
res.pcahcpc <- res.pcahcpc[,'PCA_HCPC', drop = F]

# clusters
> head(res.pcahcpc)
      PCA_HCPC
col_1        1
col_2        1
col_3        4
col_4        2
col_5        3
col_6        1

# create heatmap using PCA HCPC clustering
tmp %>%
  pheatmap(cellwidth = 15, cellheight = 15,
           annotation_col = res.pcahcpc,
           cluster_cols = pcahcpc.tree)
```

Running the above code gives me the heatmap below which is weird because it is not clustering the columns by FactorMiner PCA HCPC at all. Can someone explain why so?

[image: Heatmap]

Comment: The dendogram on the top of your plot seems to cluster the columns, am I wrong?

Comment: @carlo_sguera if you look at the corresponding PCA_HCPC annotation, it looks like it is not clustering  according to the PCA_HCPC tree. If it did, it should've shown the colors grouped together.

Comment: Now I see your point. After `res.pcahcpc <- FactoMineR::HCPC(res.pcahcpc, nb.clust = 4, graph = F)`, `plot(res.pcahcpc, choice = "tree")` is fine. However, its interaction with `pheatmap` is weird, you are right. I am not familiar with `pheatmap`, I hope you find a solution, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct dendrogram, you need first to reorder the columns of `tmp` according to the information given in `pcahcpc.tree$labels`.

```
idx <- as.numeric(gsub("col_","", pcahcpc.tree$labels))
pheatmap(tmp[, idx], cellwidth=15, cellheight=12,
         annotation_col = res.pcahcpc,
         cluster_cols = pcahcpc.tree)
```

[image]

The `pheatmap` dendogram for columns now is the same as the dendrogram given by `stats:::plot.hclust`

```
plot(pcahcpc.tree)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if I change the input matrix to this: ```set.seed(100)
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(11500), nrow = 115, ncol = 10)```

Comment: I am using this code on another dataset and it is not working, is there any way I can share that with you?

Comment: I have uploaded the input data and R script here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zRcqm-DvQtDAzd5zCknAviAYjzsuQ8rL?usp=sharing At the end of the script I am creating a heatmap, which does not seem to be clustering.

Comment: I see that you are cutting the tree using cuttree but why is it that the `res.pcahcpc$call$X$clust` and `res.pcahcpc$data.clust` have 106, 1, 7, 1 while the cuttree method is assigning 107, 1, 6, 1 to the four clusters?

Comment: @KomalRathi This is a good question. You need to better understand the output of `HCPC`. Maybe you find a bug in this function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept your answer and will let the authors know.